# CSS flexbox fill available space to the right side of a slim but high element with elements while ignoring flex-direction row/column axis restrictions

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is it possible to use **css flexbox** to fill the available space (kind of like playing tetris) ignoring the axis imposed by flex-direction **column** or **row**. The intended result should be one element on the right **el1** of which its height exceeds those of **el2** and **el3** combined and therefore **el2** and **el3** fill the available space next to **el1** naturally as follows from the **HTML** provided below.

**Intended result**

```
|------|------------------|
|      | el2              |
| el1  |------------------|
|      | el3              |
|------|------------------|
```

**Using HTML**

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="el1" style="height: 100px">
        el1
    </div>
    <div class="el2" style="height: 50px">
        el2
    </div>
    <div class="el3" style="height: 50px">
        el3
    </div>
</div>
```

The usual approach would be creating two divs in a container with **flex-direction: row** where the first div contains **el1** and the second div contains a container with **flex-direction: column** containing **el2** and **el3** as shown below:

```html
<div class="container" style="flex-direction: row">
    <div class="el1">
        el1
    </div>
    <div class="element-container" style="flex-direction: column">
        <div class="el2">
            el2
        </div>
        <div class="el3">
            el3
        </div>        
    </div>
</div>
```

This however restricts **el3** to go under **el1**+**el2** (shown below) when resizing the screen to mobile width which is the primary reason I am asking this question. Of course you can make changes in the DOM using JavaScript etc but thats not the "natural" approach I am looking for.

**Intended result in mobile screen width**

```
|------|------------------|
| el1  | el2              |
|------|------------------|
| el3                     |
|-------------------------|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use display grid along with a media query and just reorder the `grid-template-areas` from `grid-template-areas: "el1 el2" "el1 el3";` to `grid-template-areas: "el1 el2" "el3 el3";`. Display grid allows the element to be moved anywhere in its parents border-box regardless of its linear layout in the HTML markup.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 1.2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "el1 el2" 
    "el1 el3";
  height: 100vh;
}

.el1 {
  grid-area: el1;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.el2 {
  grid-area: el2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.el3 {
  grid-area: el3;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 1.2fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "el1 el2"
    "el3 el3";
    height: 100vh;
}
.el1 { grid-area: el1;}
.el2 { grid-area: el2;}
.el3 { grid-area: el3;}
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="el1"></div>
  <div class="el2"></div>
  <div class="el3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution and explanation. To be honest, this is the first time I see the CSS grid so I am now looking into creating grids. Learned something new today!

Comment: Grid is ***very*** powerful glad to have introduced you to it.